# Java, JAR in console

Tags: java, jar, terminal, console, console-application

I need to start a Java application in the console by "double-clicking" the jar file. I found a workaround to achieve that:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime()
                .exec("cmd /c start cmd.exe /k \"java -jar CourseProjectServer.jar\"");
```

It runs pretty well, sure. But as you may guess it... Creates an infinite amount of itself until I stop it cause this is basically the first line of the application so when it starts it creates a new instance.

I came up with an idea like to start the process then grab it`s PID, save it in a file for example and then checking whether it is still running but found no way to do so.

Any suggestions? Is there a proper and not idiomatic way to achieve this?

P.S.: I know I can create a bat file to start the application but I don't want to do that. If that is what you want to write - skip it.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You're guessing in the wrong direction! You may omit the call to cmd.exe and exec "java" instead, directly. But which console are you talking about, where you input the `Process p = ...`? If it is part of your program, then it is obviously already running. It's confuse. In an running app, you needn't start Java again, but could issue `CourseProjectServer.main (null);` instead, or if the main method does nothing interesting, except from calling 'new CourseProjectServer ();' call this directly. However, if the main method takes an argument i, you could test and ++i it, before starting the next.

Comment: The issue is that I have a Jar application and by default it doesn't start as a console application. It starts in a background, does it's job and quits. I don't want this behaviour I need to have a console.